# I'm trying to run python flask in vs code. I'm not able to shift to a virtual env in vscode

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux0hj.pngstrong text

As you can see in the picture I have red lines under the dbs. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: please give more info on the type of error you are getting on running the Flask app

Comment: Actually app run without any issues. Just wanted to know y those are indicated as errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the python interpreter path to python present in the virtual environment.
steps regarding how to switch interpreters is present in this article by Microsoft.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to `settings.json` file inside `.vscode` folder and update `"python.pythonPath"`.